# Getting stuck at password input for google authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, python-3.7

I'm making an application that automatically uploaded youtube videos with a given title, description, and tags, then i want to web scrape to log into youtube, with a given set of login credentials used in the google authenticator. However; this is yielded by the fact that I can't get passed the password input screen

I've tried splitting the code up into different functions, didn't work. I've tried having everything in a single function, didn't work. I've tried making a function that specifically gets access to a specific JSON element then reads that element and returns it, also didn't work. I've tried numerous different solutions when it comes to actually web scraping the password, but nothing works.

Every time I run my program and click the upload button(provided with the tkinter framework/API/library(I don't know which one of these it is)), this error appears and I've been trying to fix it for hours. But; to no avail.

this is the error I'm getting whenever I run my program and click the upload button

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/YouTube Video Uploader/uploader.py", line 36, in make_ready_to_run
    login_to_youtube()
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/YouTube Video Uploader/uploader.py", line 33, in login_to_youtube
    enter_password()
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/YouTube Video Uploader/uploader.py", line 24, in enter_password
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've researched numerous different ways how to handle this problem, like using the xpath, css selector, and class name to try and solve this problem, but it doesn't go away whenever I try to fix it.

this is all the relevant code for the program in order for you to understand it all and how it runs

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com")
window = tkinter.Tk()

def open_config_file(element_to_read_from):
    with open("config.json", "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
        for attrib in data['config']:
            return attrib[element_to_read_from]
        read_file.close()

def enter_email():
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')[0]
    python_button.send_keys(open_config_file('email'))
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]')[0]
    python_button.click()

def enter_password():
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')[0]
    python_button.send_keys(open_config_file('password'))
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]')[0]
    python_button.click()

def login_to_youtube():
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="buttons"]/ytd-button-renderer')[0]
    python_button.click()
    enter_email()
    enter_password()

def make_ready_to_run():
    login_to_youtube()

def close():
    window.quit()
    browser.quit()
    sys.exit()

def create_window():
    # added the desired buttons and text input fields
    window.title("YouTube Uploading Automated")
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Title").grid(row=0, column=0)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Description").grid(row=1, column=0)
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Tags").grid(row=2, column=0)
    title_entry = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=0, column=1)
    description_entry = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=1, column=1)
    tags_entry = tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=2, column=1)
    tkinter.Button(window, text="Upload", fg="green", command=make_ready_to_run).grid(row=3, column=0)
    tkinter.Button(window, text="Quit", fg="red", command=close).grid(row=3, column=1)
    window.mainloop()

def main():
    create_window()
```

the error is happening on this line below:

```py
python_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')[0]
```

I expect the program to click on the password input field and then type in the users password. Afters wards; it clicks the upload video button on the YouTube home screen and lets the user input the file path of the video and then the program still takes control of the user's browser and such until it has finished with it's automation and then closes itself, but not the browser(because the video is uploading and in order for you to transfer the video's data to YouTube's server is by letting the data transfer via the internet. And, closing your browser can hinder, or even completely stop this process entirely.)

Again, this is the error I'm continuously getting when I click the upload button in the tkinter side of things.

File "C:/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/YouTube Video Uploader/uploader.py", line 24, in enter_password
    python_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you verified that `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')` is returning what you're assuming it's returning?

Comment: Well, it's been happening whenever I try `browser.find_elements_by_xpath()[0]` and `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector()[0]` aswell as; `browser.find_elements_by_id()[0]`. And all of these produce the same error shown above.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. The problem is that you're assuming the `find_elements` command is returning something. It is not returning what you think it's returning. The problem isn't with the index, it's with you making assumptions about the data that was returned.

Comment: Oh, well I guess that would be the problem then. Could you try and help me with this problem? I'm not very experienced with selenium(having only started using it, about a week ago.) I'm sorry for not explaining, or answering any questions that you had.